# value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'addSubview' Swift2

Tags: ios, swift

I have this error:

> value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'addSubview'

in this code. Do you know why?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.currentViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ComponentA")
    self.currentViewController!.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.addChildViewController(self.currentViewController!)
    self.addSubview(self.currentViewController?.view, toView: self.containerView)
    super.viewDidLoad()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`self` is an instance of `UIViewController`. It defines methods like `viewDidLoad()`, `addChildViewController()`, etc.

The method `addSubview()` is instead defined on the class `UIView`. If the view controller has a view set for its `view` property, you can access it with the call `self.view.addSubview()`.

Answer (score 6):

addSubview is method of UIView and not UIViewController

you have to add a view do:

```
   self.view.addSubview(YOUR_VIEW)
```

you if want to add a viewController

```
   addChildViewController(YOUR_CHILDCONTROLLER)
```